# Pensar en las musarañas. Can it be used for a direct meaning or is it too figurative?

Tags: modismos

Pensar en las musarañas means to daydream. When I checked with AI it agrees but states it has to be explained more. I don't trust AI in some ways.

I wrote:

> Me encierro en mi habitación para que pueda pensar en las musurañas.

It was suggested that I add something like:

> Me pierdo en mis pensamientos

Is this really necessary?
I checked in the Collins Dictionary. It gives the example:

> Por la mañana, los que puedan, que se queden en la cama -manta ligera-, y a pensar en las musarañas.
> <sub>*El Mundo del Siglo Veintiuno (1994)*</sub>

I know "soñar despierto" is another way to say daydream but I like the other idiom.
Can I just use it and be understood with no further explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más habitual en español es:

> Soñar despierto

> Estar ido

> Estar en las nubes

Aunque esta última también se aplica a precios elevados de la compra cambiando la preposición *con* por *por*: *¡Los precios están por las nubes!*

> Estar en babia

<sub>*RAE [babia](https://dle.rae.es/babia)*</sub>

Comment: gracias. Sí,ya las conozco. La frase propia , qué piensa usted?

Comment: La de las musarañas? Es más bien antigua.

Comment: @Danielillo.se puede usarla hoy en día ? y necesitará otra explicación para entender el sentido?